# Using Python, extract and print items from a matrix containing list elements

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have a matrix of lists of the following form.

```
[[[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c]],
 [[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c]],
 [[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c]],
 [[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c]],
 [[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c]],
]
```

Using Python, I would like to print a matrix by extracting one item from each of the inner lists ([f,g,h,c]).  For example extract the c element from each inner list:

```
[[c,c,c,c,c,c],
 [c,c,c,c,c,c],
 [c,c,c,c,c,c],
 [c,c,c,c,c,c],
 [c,c,c,c,c,c]]
```

Comment: yeah, what have you tried, but I also have problems with understanding what do you want to achieve? Which element do you want to extract from the lists? The 4-th element? The one, that begins with the char 'c'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print([[x[3] for x in y] for y in matrix])
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use numpy?

```
>>>a = [[range(4) for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(4)]
>>>import numpy
>>>b = numpy.array(a)
>>>b
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3]],

   [[0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3]],

   [[0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3]],

   [[0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [0, 1, 2, 3]]])
>>>a[:, :, -1]
array([[3, 3, 3, 3],
   [3, 3, 3, 3],
   [3, 3, 3, 3],
   [3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
f,g,h,c = (1,2,3,4)

matrix = [
 [[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c]],
 [[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c]],
 [[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c]],
 [[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c]],
 [[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c],[f,g,h,c]],
]

import operator
print [map(operator.itemgetter(3), x) for x in matrix]
```